# Invariant Violation: In order to initialize Apollo Client, you must specify 'link' and 'cache' properties in the options object in Unit Test case

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, react-apollo

I have the following a.jsx file which returns the apollo client object from it:

```
import { createAppSyncLink } from "aws-appsync";
import { ApolloClient } from "apollo-client";
import { InMemoryCache } from "apollo-cache-inmemory";
import { ApolloLink } from "apollo-link";
import { appSyncConfig } from "./client/AwsConfig";
import { fragmentMatcher } from "./client/apollo-cache";

// AppSync link
const awsAppSyncLink = createAppSyncLink({
    url: appSyncConfig.graphqlEndpoint,
    region: appSyncConfig.region,
    auth: {
        type: appSyncConfig.authenticationType,
        apiKey: appSyncConfig.apiKey
    }
});

const links = [awsAppSyncLink];

const apolloLink = ApolloLink.from(links);

export default new ApolloClient({
    cache: new InMemoryCache({ fragmentMatcher }),
    link: apolloLink
});
```

Now, I am trying to run test for this file as following using jest:

```
import { createAppSyncLink } from "aws-appsync";
import { ApolloLink } from "apollo-link";

jest.mock("aws-appsync");
jest.mock("apollo-link");

describe("GraphQL client", () => {

    it("should create a client", () => {
        const client = require("../src/a").default;

        console.log(client);

        expect(client).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

But I am getting the following error:

> FAIL  tst/a.test.js   ● GraphQL client › should create a client
>
> ```
> Invariant Violation: In order to initialize Apollo Client, you must specify 'link' and 'cache' properties in the options object.
> These options are part of the upgrade requirements when migrating from Apollo Client 1.x to Apollo Client 2.x.
> For more information, please visit: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/tutorial/client.html#apollo-client-setup
>
>   26 | const apolloLink = ApolloLink.from(links);
>   27 |
> > 28 | export default new ApolloClient({
>      |                ^
>   29 |     cache: new InMemoryCache({ fragmentMatcher }),
>   30 |     link: apolloLink
>   31 | });
>
>   at new InvariantError (node_modules/ts-invariant/lib/invariant.esm.js:12:28)
>   at new ApolloClient (node_modules/apollo-client/bundle.umd.js:2484:92)
>   at Object.<anonymous> (src/a.jsx:28:16)
>   at Object.<anonymous> (tst/a.test.js:10:24)
> ```

I am pretty new to testing in Javascript and using jest. If someone can help me in writing the test case for this file, it would be great and how do you go about it?